# Sproutcore Datastore Local Storage sync

Tags: local-storage, datastore, sproutcore, web-sql

I was wondering if it is possible to sync the Sproutcore Datastore (in-memory) with a choice of browser storage mechanisms such as WebSQL, localStorage etc.

I do know about SC.UserDefaults but my use case is not about saving app-level or user-level settings.

If there is no such in-built way to achieve this, is there a project attempting to do this somewhere that I could fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at the SCUDS framework.  Specifically this part

https://github.com/etgryphon/sproutcore-uds/tree/master/frameworks/local/lib/adaptors

they have some adaptors in there for lawnchair and some client side sql libraries.  Other than that I think you will have to roll your own.

Comment: Yup the SCUDS project is the only public one that's available that I'm aware (I helped write it), though only the localStorage section has been put to the test in production. If you want to contribute a working indexDB adaptor, that'd be awesome!